# Bash: Quotation in command substitution

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, command-substitution

In short, I want to use directories listed by a command in a `find` command:

```
find $(produces_dir_names --options...) -find-options...
```

The problem comes with white space in the directory names. I thought quoting them in the output of the producing command (which I can change) would be enough:

```
"a" "a b" "a b c"
```

but bash complains:

```
find: ‘"a"’: No such file or directory
find: ‘"a’: No such file or directory
find: ‘b"’: No such file or directory
find: ‘"a’: No such file or directory
find: ‘b’: No such file or directory
find: ‘c"’: No such file or directory
```

As you can, see `bash` will split the output of the command on spaces, even with the quotation marks.
I tried to fiddle with `IFS` and set it to `\n`,
but my understanding of it seems too limited to get it working.

The only workaround I found was in this Stack Overflow question:
[bash command substitution remove quotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31203003/3530184),
namely putting an `eval` in front of it, but this seems kind of ugly.

My Questions:

Is there an easy way and how would it look like to write this substitution, without the `eval`?

Are the quotations even necessary?

Example (producing the same output):

```
find $(echo '"a" "a b" "a b c"')
```

Comment: This is the famous [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) problem, also discussed extensively [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).  You might be able to find a way to make it work, but it's almost always going to be fraught.  Also, setting `IFS` to `\n` isn't safe either, because filenames can contain `\n`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I used the output of another try, which was `ls $(produces_dir_names --options...)`  to see if find was not understanding the output of the substituion correctly. I changed the example output in my question.

Comment: It pretty much doesn't matter what the "outer" command is, when the inner command is supposed to produce a list of filenames to operate on it's going to be subject to word splitting and processing in ways that are not meant to apply to filenames, so you're going to have a really hard time making it work right.  You're usually better of just finding another approach than trying to make it work with all filenames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe in two lines

```
IFS=$'\n' DIRS=( $(produces_dir_names --options...) ) 
find "${DIRS[@]}" -find-options...
```

Example:

```
$ mkdir -p "/tmp/test/a b/foo" "/tmp/test/x y/bar"

$ IFS=$'\n' DIRS=( $(printf "/tmp/test/a b\n/tmp/test/x y\n") )
$ find "${DIRS[@]}" -mindepth 1
/tmp/test/a b/foo
/tmp/test/x y/bar
```

But in general this is no good style. For example you will be in trouble if your DIRS contain newlines. Better fix your "produces_dir_names" to print null byte terminated strings. Regarding my example this would be something like:

```
$ printf "/tmp/test/a b\0/tmp/test/x y\0" | xargs -0 -I '{}' find '{}' -mindepth 1
/tmp/test/a b/foo
/tmp/test/x y/bar
```

If you can't fix "produces_dir_names", regarding my last comment, the most general solution would look like this:

```
produces_dir_names --options... | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0  -I '{}' find '{}' -find-options...
```

Still problems with "newlines" unless you fix "produces_dir_names" to avoid `tr`.

Comment: I suspect this will have trouble with any filenames that contain `\n`, which is a legal character in paths/filenames.

Comment: @EricRenouf  But this is what the OP wants. I'll add a comment.

Comment: `IFS` is being set globally, not just locally to the assignment to `DIRS`. I would use `readarray -t DIRS < <(produces_dir_names --options ...)` (or the equivalent `while` loop prior to `bash` 4) instead.

Comment: In bash IFS is only changed for that commandline. Compare `VAR=a; VAR="b" true; echo "$VAR"` and .`VAR=a; VAR="b"; echo "$VAR"`. `readarray` looks good!

Comment: This works for my current setup. And yes I could manipulate the producing command so it would delimit the path with \0. But since I also, somewhat control the input (sorry for not mentioning that) I did not bother. But you're right that I should take \0 delimiting into consideration.
And since every xargs command I checked(gnu, freebsd and netbsd) would understand -0 i'm satisfied with this.

Answer (score 1):

[rudimeier’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/318583/80216#318591) is good — specifically,
the part about modifying `produces_dir_names`
to print null-terminated strings —
but it might not be obvious from his answer
that it executes `find` once for each directory. 
If this is good enough, than fine. 
But, of course, it is possible to invoke `find`
with multiple starting points; e.g.,

```
find  dir1 dir2 dir3  -find-options...
```

and it appears from the question that that’s what you want. 
This can be done as follows:

```
printf "a\0a b\0a b c" | xargs -0 sh -c 'find "$@" -find-options...' sh
```

This causes `xargs` to invoke `sh -c` once,
with all the directory names appended to the command. 
The shell will then expand `"$@"` to a list of those directory names.

P.S. If `produces_dir_names` lists too many directory names
to put on one command line,
then `xargs` will be forced to spawn a few commands. 
Use `xargs --verbose` to see what commands `xargs` is spawning.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear up the mystery of the error messages you are getting:

> ```
> find: ‘"a"’: No such file or directory
> find: ‘"a’: No such file or directory
> find: ‘b"’: No such file or directory
> find: ‘"a’: No such file or directory
> find: ‘b’: No such file or directory
> find: ‘c"’: No such file or directory
> ```

The answer is that **Bash quote removal doesn't remove quotes that *resulted* from command substitution.**

From `LESS='+/^ *Quote Removal' man bash`

> ```
> Quote Removal
>     After the preceding expansions, all unquoted occurrences of the charac-
>     ters  \,  ', and " that did not result from one of the above expansions
>     are removed.
> ```

The "preceding expansions" referenced include:

> ```
> EXPANSION
>    Brace Expansion
>    Tilde Expansion
>    Parameter Expansion
>    Command Substitution
>    Arithmetic Expansion
>    Process Substitution
>    Word Splitting
>    Pathname Expansion
>    Quote Removal
> ```

Comment: Arguably, this is obvious.  If I say `a="Don't say I didn't warn you."; echo "$a"`, the output is `Don't say I didn't warn you.`; the single quotes (a.k.a. apostrophes) are not removed or even recognized.

Comment: @G-Man, good thing I'm not arguing, then.  Just clarifying.  :)  Direct quote from the Original Poster: *"I thought quoting them in the output of the producing command...would be enough."*

Comment: I don't really care about the qoutes more about the word spliting since this is the only thing that matters to the invokation of 'find'.